# How to query MongoDb Collection with C# Driver by having dictionary values as filter parameters

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

I have a list of Events

Where Event is

```
public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Seq { get; set; }

        public Event(int id, int seq)
        {
            Id = id;
            Seq = seq;
        }
    }
```

I want to query on that list and only get Events with lets say Id value 1 and 2.

Then only get the entries of Event with Id 1 that have Seq equal or bigger that 3

And only get the entries of Event with Id 2 that have Seq equal or bigger that 4

In a LINQ example I created a Dictionary "eventsToRetrieve" of int,int with the values I want to get as described above

```
[1,3]
[2,4]
```

A code example with C#/LINQ would looks like this

```
 var allEvents = new List<Event>()
            {
                new Event(1, 1),
                new Event(1, 2),
                new Event(1, 3),
                new Event(1, 4),
                new Event(1, 5),
                new Event(2, 1),
                new Event(2, 2),
                new Event(2, 3),
                new Event(2, 4),
                new Event(2, 5),
                new Event(2, 6),
                new Event(3, 1),
                new Event(3, 2),
                new Event(3, 3),
            };

            var eventsToRetrieve = new Dictionary<int, int>()
            {
                { 1 ,3},
                { 2 ,4}
            };


            var eventsIWant = allEvents
           .Where(ev => eventsToRetrieve.Keys.Contains(ev.Id) 
               && ev.Seq >= eventsToRetrieve.Single(er => er.Key == ev.Id).Value 
           ).ToList();
```

This LINQ works fine and I get the expected results.
The result "eventsIWant" are only the events with values

```
(1,3)
(1,4)
(1,5)
(2,4)
(2,5)
(2,6)
```

**Now I want to apply something similar on a mongoDb Collection** that looks like the list above. I have an eventsCollection with a composite Key (Id) that is a unique combination of (EntityId, SequenceNumber) pairs.

The Event class is

```cs
    public class Event
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The composite key for this Event
        /// </summary>
        [BsonId]
        public EventId Id { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class EventId
    {
        public Guid EntityId { get; private set; }
        public long SequenceNumber { get; private set; }
    }
```

I have tried something like

```cs
var eventsIWant = await _eventsCollection.FindAsync( event => eventsToRetrieve.Keys.Contains(event.Id.EntityId)
&& event.Id.SequenceNumber >= eventsToRetrieve[event.Id.EntityId])
```

But I get

```
System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter MONGODB C#...
```

for the

```
events.Id.SequenceNumber >= sitesWithLatestSequence[events.Id.EntityId])
```

part.

I also tried something similar with the C# / MongoDB aggregation framework but couldn't get something working

Is there a way to do something similar with what the LINQ did but as a mongo MongoDB filter or Aggregation ?

Sorry if the title is not very accurate but couldn't come up with something better. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Does the query need to be dynamic or are there always 2 pairs of numbers to filter by?
In case it always 2 pairs, you can create a simple filter without the use of a dictionary.
In case the number of pairs is dynamic, you may have to use expression trees, since it seems the Mongo DB driver can't work with dictionaries/hashes.
Or, use Mongo DB aggregation framework as you tried.

Comment: it is dynamic yeah. The eventsToRetrieve be it a dictinary or a tuple or whatever is meant to describe < "The EntityId I want" ,"From which sequnceNumber and onwards?" >. I may want Id 1 from seq 3 only . Or 1,3 and 2,4. Or 2,4 and 3,5 and 6,3 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (couldn't test it, but hopefully it's close enough):

```
    var eventsToRetrieve = new Dictionary<Guid, long>()
    {
        { Guid.NewGuid() ,3},
        { Guid.NewGuid() ,4}
    };

    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Event));
    Expression idExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, nameof(Event.Id));

    var body = 
        eventsToRetrieve.Aggregate(null, (Expression expression, KeyValuePair<Guid,long> etr) => 

        {
            var addedExpression =        
                                Expression.AndAlso(
                                Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(idExpression, nameof(EventId.EntityId)), Expression.Constant(etr.Key)),
                                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Property(idExpression, nameof(EventId.SequenceNumber)), Expression.Constant(etr.Value)));
            return expression != null ? Expression.OrElse(expression,addedExpression) : addedExpression;
        });


    var filter = (Expression<Func<Event,bool>>) Expression.Lambda(body, parameterExpression);
```

Comment: Not sure what I am meant to do with that LambdaExpression ?

Comment: Cast it into a mongo db filter type ?

Comment: Added a cast.
The mongo API allows passing experssions as filters, projections etc.
If I recall, you can simply do:
collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter);
Where filter is the filter from my code.

Comment: Also its SiteEvent.Id.EntityId , Event.Id is a composite key that has EntityId , Sequence number.

Comment: collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter); tried that but wasnt accepting it.

Comment: Need to fix something regarding the composite key, I get "ex={System.ArgumentException: 'EntityId' is not a member of type 'Event.}"

Comment: What was the error for

collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter)?

Comment: Please edit the original question with the real Event class.

Comment: Updated with the actual types of Event / EventId.

Comment: Hmmm run that, seems to be getting an exception of 

"{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: itemName
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[T](T value, String paramName)...."

Comment: Do you think something like lookup of aggregate framework could work?

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
            var allEvents = new List<Event>()
            {
                new Event(1, 1),
                new Event(1, 2),
                new Event(1, 3),
                new Event(1, 4),
                new Event(1, 5),
                new Event(2, 1),
                new Event(2, 2),
                new Event(2, 3),
                new Event(2, 4),
                new Event(2, 5),
                new Event(2, 6),
                new Event(3, 1),
                new Event(3, 2),
                new Event(3, 3),
            };

            Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = allEvents
                .GroupBy(x => x.Id, y => y.Seq)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            Dictionary<int, List<int>> results = dict.Where(x => x.Value.Any(y => y >= 4))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => y.Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Where(z => z.Any(a => a >= 4)).SelectMany(a => a.Where(b => b >= 4)).ToList());

        }
```

Comment: Hey , The LINQ works fine. Its the mongo filter that needs a different approach. Thanks.